# "Host key verification failed" during docker alpine 9 build

Tags: git, docker, alpine-linux

I'm trying to clone a private git repo and am running into this error:

```
npm ERR! Host key verification failed.
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! exited with error code: 128
```

Looks like I need to  add the git host to the `known_hosts` file. However, this version of alpine from Docker does not have a `~/.ssh/known_host`  file.

the `/etc/ssh/` is present.

Comment: Did you try adding your own `known_hosts` file? e.g. put in a `echo 'git.example.com,192.168.234.100 ssh-rsa theverylongbase64key' >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts` somewhere between `apk add openssh-client` and whatever command (looks like something launched with node) is doing the git operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to manually add hosts:

ssh-keyscan -Ht ecdsa  >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts

---

below comment was correct:

Did you try adding your own known_hosts file? e.g. put in a echo 'git.example.com,192.168.234.100 ssh-rsa theverylongbase64key' >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts somewhere between apk add openssh-client and whatever command (looks like something launched with node) is doing the git operation. – wmorrell Feb 19 at 23:36 - WMORRELL

Answer (score 3):

Using `https` does not need SSH keys to be setup and will not ask for a password:

```
git clone https://github.com/<username>/<repo name>.git
```